# Different properties files for WebDriverEventListener and Log4j in same script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, log4j

I want use both `WebDriverEventListner` and `Log4j` in my automation script.

I want to create one log for all the `WebDriverEventListner` actions and different log for `Log4j` actions.

I have two property files as below:

```
# for Log4j actions - userDefinedLog.properties
# Define the root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE, HTML

# Define the appender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.HTML=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

#Define the file location
log4j.appender.HTML.File=./target/Log/userDefinedLog.html

#Define the layout and pattern
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.HTML.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.Title=User Defined Log
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.LocationInfo=true

log4j.appender.FA.append=false
```

---

```
#for WebDriverEventListner actions - webDriverEventListner.properties
# Define the root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE, HTML

# Define the appender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.HTML=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

#Define the file location
log4j.appender.HTML.File=./target/Log/eventListener.html

#Define the layout and pattern
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.HTML.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.Title=WebDriver Event Listener Log
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.LocationInfo=true

log4j.appender.FA.append=false
```

Now I have to specify or initiate these property files to `Log4j` and `WebDriverEventListner` separately.

Please help me on this.